# How to make two different types of registration and login in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have two different types of users employees and customers.  how to make to different types of registration and login  and i want to redirect them to different page. 
I am new in django but i want to learn this things. 
I had searched every where but i don't find any solutions
Is this possible to make two different types of user login and registration in django?
Help will be appreciated  and motivation for me to learn django
Thanking you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

## try to learn the models and forms in django first

buy creating to different models and making it's form you can easily create two reg and login

1. models
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/
2. forms
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/
3. templates
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/

Comment: Is there any tutorial related to my question?

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html